# how to use second and 3rd partitions in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

How I can use second and 3rd partitions in ubuntu through terminal as path like: /home/usr etc ...
I have 3 partions 1st windows(NTFS), 2nd shared (FAT), 3rd ubuntu (EXT4). what should i type in the terminal to access files of 2nd partition

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the partitions first. The easiest way I know to do this: Open nautilus -> Click on the partition to mount in the left pane (If you don't see the left pane, activate it by using F9 key). 
Once the partitions are mounted, you can access them from /media directory. /media is the directory where the mounted devices like usb pendrives, partitions etc. are present as a part of filesystem tree. The partitions are treated just as another directory you create usin mkdir command. 
So after mounting the drives, Opne the terminal:

- Type 
  cd /media;
- Type ls (to see the mounted partitions)
- Use cd command to enter the drives(partitions). Its just another directory for you. Use commands like cp, mv, ls and any other command you would use to manipulate other files normal in directories.
  NOTE: If you want to mount the partitions too from command line you can use mount command to mount them 
  Use something like sudo mkdir /media/drivex; mount /dev/sda[number] /media/drivex; [number]=the partition number you want to access.